# FTP file listing crash (iOS 6.1)

Tags: ftp, crash, file-listing, ios6.1

I have waited for iOS 6.1 hoping that it can solve some network issue I have discovered during the development of my application (with iOS 6.0.x). Actually, the iOS 6.1 resolve some of these issues, but unfortunately other still occurs. I have opened a bug report to Apple, but my customer (a big company) needs to show the application soon and this instability is a severe limitation. :(  I ask here hoping that somebody have discovered this problem and found a workaround. Basically I performs some consecutive file listing through a FTP daemon (vsftpd). Randomly, the application crash inside the following selector:

```
[self.networkStream open];
```

I have reproduced it by simply get the Apple's FTPSample project and replace the 'listOrCancelAction' selector of the file 'ListController.m' with the following:

```
- (IBAction)listOrCancelAction:(id)sender
{
    #pragma unused(sender)
    if (!self.isReceiving)
        [self startReceive];
    [self performSelector:@selector(listOrCancelAction:) withObject:sender afterDelay:1.0];
}
```

This way you can click the 'List' button only one time. After a while the application crash.

My environment:

- Mac OS X 10.7.4;
- XCode 4.6 (iOS SDK 6.1);
- iPad3 updated to iOS 6.1;

Stack trace:

```
Incident Identifier: BAE3971A-4C82-4D91-A5FE-34748740CEB4
CrashReporter Key:   d89bdbe7d8601b5d1230f3e2dbe4d7164277af23
Hardware Model:      iPad3,1
Process:         FTPSample [5102]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/622BE7B0-B65D-40B4-BCBA-62BCF71657CA/FTPSample.app/FTPSample
Identifier:      FTPSample
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-02-09 20:12:40.211 +0100
OS Version:      iOS 6.1 (10B141)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000030
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CFNetwork                       0x31c8ec24 _ZL13_WriteCommandP26_CFFTPNetConnectionContextP19_CFFTPStreamContextPK10__CFString + 64
1   CFNetwork                       0x31c8ed8a _ZL13_StartProcessP26_CFFTPNetConnectionContextP19_CFFTPStreamContext + 222
2   CFNetwork                       0x31c8e72c _ZL33_FTPConnectionRequestStateChangedP19_CFFTPStreamContextN13NetConnection5StateEP13CFStreamErrorP21NetConnection_ClassicP26_CFFTPNetConnectionContext + 108
3   CFNetwork                       0x31cb5b3a NetConnection_Classic::requestStateChanged(void*, NetConnection::State, CFStreamError*) + 26
4   CFNetwork                       0x31c65ee0 NetConnection::enqueue(void*, unsigned char) + 316
5   CFNetwork                       0x31c8c1ce _ZL14_FTPStreamOpenPKvP13CFStreamErrorPhP19_CFFTPStreamContext + 3414
6   CFNetwork                       0x31cfbcbe CoreReadStreamWithCallBacks::_streamImpl_Open(CFStreamError*, unsigned char*) + 38
7   CFNetwork                       0x31cfbdae non-virtual thunk to CoreReadStreamWithCallBacks::_streamImpl_Open(CFStreamError*, unsigned char*) + 6
8   CFNetwork                       0x31cfd04a CoreStreamBase::_streamInterface_Open() + 42
9   CFNetwork                       0x31cfb7b8 CoreStreamCFStreamSupport<__CFReadStream*, CoreReadStream>::_stream_open(__CFReadStream*, CFStreamError*, unsigned char*, void*) + 36
10  CoreFoundation                  0x31f4d3f4 _CFStreamOpen + 72
11  CoreFoundation                  0x31f682f6 CFReadStreamOpen + 86
12  FTPSample                       0x0008083e -[ListController startReceive] (ListController.m:184)
13  FTPSample                       0x000815fc -[ListController listOrCancelAction:] (ListController.m:393)
14  UIKit                           0x33eed0c0 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 68
15  UIKit                           0x33eed148 -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 116
16  UIKit                           0x33eed0c0 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 68
17  UIKit                           0x33eed072 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 26
18  UIKit                           0x33eed050 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 40
19  UIKit                           0x33eec906 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 498
20  UIKit                           0x33eecdfc -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 484
21  UIKit                           0x33e155ec -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 520
22  UIKit                           0x33e027fc -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 376
23  UIKit                           0x33e02116 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6150
24  GraphicsServices                0x35af45a0 _PurpleEventCallback + 588
25  GraphicsServices                0x35af41ce PurpleEventCallback + 30
26  CoreFoundation                  0x31fcf170 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
27  CoreFoundation                  0x31fcf112 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
28  CoreFoundation                  0x31fcdf94 __CFRunLoopRun + 1380
29  CoreFoundation                  0x31f40eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
30  CoreFoundation                  0x31f40d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
31  GraphicsServices                0x35af32e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
32  UIKit                           0x33e562fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
33  FTPSample                       0x0007ad90 main (main.m:61)
34  FTPSample                       0x0007a354 start + 36

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a373648 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a2a3974 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 792
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a2a3654 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 32

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a372eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a373048 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x31fcf040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3   CoreFoundation                  0x31fcdd9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
4   CoreFoundation                  0x31f40eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x31f40d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                         0x37f26500 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 440
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2dc30e _pthread_start + 306
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2dc1d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a383d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2d1cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2d1a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2d18a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a383d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2d1cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2d1a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2d18a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a383d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2d1cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2d1a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2d18a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a383594 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x31fd31f2 __CFSocketManager + 674
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2dc30e _pthread_start + 306
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a2dc1d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000007    r1: 0x1f84c9f8      r2: 0x1f84c9f8      r3: 0x00000004
    r4: 0x00000000    r5: 0x1f852a30      r6: 0x00000007      r7: 0x2fd86518
    r8: 0x0000000b    r9: 0x000a1934     r10: 0x1f858e70     r11: 0x1f84c9f0
    ip: 0x3a492970    sp: 0x2fd864e8      lr: 0x31c8ec1f      pc: 0x31c8ec24
  cpsr: 0x60000030

Binary Images:
   0x79000 -    0x8dfff +FTPSample armv7  <3a5b53df672035cc91392e17de53022d> /var/mobile/Applications/622BE7B0-B65D-40B4-BCBA-62BCF71657CA/FTPSample.app/FTPSample
0x2feea000 - 0x2ff0afff  dyld armv7  <454baf45f9a831aa88e1ea4447c58d4e> /usr/lib/dyld
0x31202000 - 0x31202fff  Accelerate armv7  <b68ff92e404931f3bcb6361720f77724> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x31203000 - 0x31341fff  vImage armv7  <30522b92940d3dd184c8e46780594048> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x31342000 - 0x31425fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <d8edada1cea133458ca779e34a3a7f88> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x31426000 - 0x316dbfff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <9e08aead79d13043bab622402a270fba> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x316dc000 - 0x31735fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <09e2a5e3e9203950890ba57592523132> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x31736000 - 0x31747fff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <7b7d4ccc9f2b364cb0da4251e745545d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x31748000 - 0x31748fff  vecLib armv7  <a7751c047dcc35ba8885212e1938b93f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x31c4f000 - 0x31d14fff  CFNetwork armv7  <4771a5e4f9b83bceb252f0f3d166aaca> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x31d15000 - 0x31d6bfff  CoreAudio armv7  <5d534dbf76ff30f4a628f25f56c5f26a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x31f38000 - 0x3206afff  CoreFoundation armv7  <fcb8d4e838543bcb9a52c9f232b8b4eb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x3206b000 - 0x321a3fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <81e213f810a034d4ba411f9b505da2a6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x321a5000 - 0x321e0fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <a5d20b80ab1532d8831027a66d2d9eb5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x323c4000 - 0x323dffff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <ec1487f9bdb93597a3f8d434406ad9bf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x323e0000 - 0x32495fff  CoreImage armv7  <6ae4ae2461313e3f84c6a8102d5b1b0e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x32523000 - 0x32588fff  CoreMedia armv7  <8592bdc268b83b8886acfc1fdab649ed> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x32612000 - 0x32668fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <c5a2e59bb15d35b8a8e356e129b78b5e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x32669000 - 0x326cbfff  CoreText armv7  <e135debbc8f937299f4986fc3e9459e3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x326cc000 - 0x326dbfff  CoreVideo armv7  <00f18bb26e663da9ae251a6ec36a19ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x32860000 - 0x32a23fff  Foundation armv7  <0179934581d13346aa7583165108b95c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x32bde000 - 0x32c27fff  IOKit armv7  <a98ba9fefc7333e4a5a9169198848c62> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x32c28000 - 0x32e00fff  ImageIO armv7  <b5ce84bb074d3de4b07b55da9fd8bfd1> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x33317000 - 0x33370fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <77da8a9e7f813f5baf37eaa4a87fae84> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x3345f000 - 0x33466fff  OpenGLES armv7  <f2ede6b206f336de82cc38619692e762> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x33468000 - 0x33468fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <2506af1c983f3f09ac69aca44f67e863> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x3346c000 - 0x3346efff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <af6ff28dce6031baaa850ccc79e5699b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x3346f000 - 0x33473fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <a6ac1673a088379aa512ba5cac301f5b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x33474000 - 0x334b1fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <b8b8f3a1bfd0345e86aa0c2952534949> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x33bac000 - 0x33cc1fff  QuartzCore armv7  <c086b6e6cd9d341399bcc3675c82f1fe> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x33d10000 - 0x33d3efff  Security armv7  <fbc24f15bd9e37539cdd6e3576bde938> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x33dbd000 - 0x33dfcfff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <410d69b356e533d6a1d538cf33059634> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x33dff000 - 0x34353fff  UIKit armv7  <ad8b3ad23f413187a178179db39cfa6b> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x34354000 - 0x34392fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <d2e8067306d9346ab4a448f10f336894> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x3465c000 - 0x3465ffff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <a2170ad876f13ef1b944547913d05af2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x34a8b000 - 0x34ac6fff  AppSupport armv7  <921794b7d82a3558a0eb860979be199c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x34b39000 - 0x34b42fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <de7ca29cd47433cd8eca9c04102f5508> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x34b71000 - 0x34b88fff  BackBoardServices armv7  <585cc62d83c530ee82988de940c1e161> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x34b92000 - 0x34bb6fff  Bom armv7  <b5315d733e123a0781683efdc734064b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x34dec000 - 0x34df1fff  CommonUtilities armv7  <f8fea9ee6ca236b0a7fa6c00eb8a0d24> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x350b7000 - 0x350b8fff  CoreSurface armv7  <6065f7e040e93d6ea2837e929592cc30> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x35125000 - 0x3512afff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <03ee46e3ca3f3920a7174e62096723fb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x35351000 - 0x3536afff  DictionaryServices armv7  <84669055e3e63d6ab56b8fe7b0476aaa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x353dd000 - 0x357f0fff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <43de0b31da3b39e4acf85ec2c8d5c65c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x359e8000 - 0x359f4fff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <d77ad2367fff37d485480aa39df7d325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x35aee000 - 0x35af9fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <d4b7fd6509753bff9525fef374ddc359> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x35de5000 - 0x35e31fff  IMFoundation armv7  <797535fc363c3f818bcd1424251393bf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x35e38000 - 0x35e39fff  IOAccelerator armv7  <9655464326203d258d3d0fc7e94651e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x35e3a000 - 0x35e3ffff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <f38c374982a931d5a47458dd3c34ac59> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x35e40000 - 0x35e44fff  IOSurface armv7  <a55bf03c35de3fd9b56dce82083c3d10> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x35e8e000 - 0x36034fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <a5780997f4b738659172f40877c9a7d9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x3632f000 - 0x3635cfff  MobileAsset armv7  <3a9e6258ae1230f5b12f1638b09cb974> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x363a1000 - 0x363a4fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <c63e4b1ae40635cd9c6a7de851c80d10> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x363a5000 - 0x363abfff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <35882c57076334aeb0641969a9b69ff3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x36408000 - 0x3640bfff  MobileSystemServices armv7  <10b4eee2739c353183ac2cfe4e39a443> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x36cf8000 - 0x36d1dfff  OpenCL armv7  <5bf059a9deb632678d70099f14f51b82> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x37331000 - 0x37359fff  PrintKit armv7  <3f0b9c58a458358eb506858e8ff9e1fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x3735a000 - 0x373cefff  ProofReader armv7  <9cb25467554637bcb268ba30527d3c0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x37513000 - 0x37524fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <e2571f80a0ad3dc580c69794457bd887> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x376af000 - 0x376b1fff  TCC armv7  <d5bef30a5bda315194173b862975f9fb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x376d0000 - 0x376ddfff  TelephonyUtilities armv7  <803d7a92439238ee942086999c481eb6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities.framework/TelephonyUtilities
0x37b60000 - 0x37c00fff  UIFoundation armv7  <9a464526e26634bc834537e5ac3abf1f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x37efc000 - 0x37f1bfff  WebBookmarks armv7  <77b65bc9c87b367ebea9a5b7984b13a5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x37f1c000 - 0x3884bfff  WebCore armv7  <ce52fd40ccc236c4b86c020beabb1bb0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x3884c000 - 0x38929fff  WebKit armv7  <dee20c7689bc3e029172b488d8c5f772> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x389d4000 - 0x389dbfff  XPCObjects armv7  <723fe314ab95381cbfa69a0000005692> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
0x396fe000 - 0x39704fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <f40705b5e9c43ce3b1f185fe690b9ac8> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x39705000 - 0x3971bfff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <5a8a3d18a1ff3c97bd773705fef2d81c> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x39733000 - 0x3973ffff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <ea41737238273d73b173ec09358d7b62> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x39751000 - 0x39751fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <7aeeab280f7e361e9986d962d0fa5281> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x3986f000 - 0x3987bfff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <3870b1c8b1783b788bd51da1a04eae6e> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x3987c000 - 0x39885fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <b04d27fa0f2d31d8bd0745f8aa0d7f67> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x39886000 - 0x398d0fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <ceb9fb64fb203d3a94063a9db6590ca4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x398d1000 - 0x398e4fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <4b8520bc534231ae97ce146e076bc7bf> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x39915000 - 0x39a02fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <ac23bb84e91e35418c9a2fb4792658b2> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x39a03000 - 0x39b4cfff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <da9d04cc6f6d3825aa52636342ef1e04> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x39b54000 - 0x39b54fff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <a10d8f96815d35e0a1d2c7b998a941f3> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x39b57000 - 0x39b5efff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <996afbc31d8b3f2a907be2427509a4c8> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x39e7d000 - 0x39f7bfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <79e5d714945834e4b2587abfc6c7269c> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x3a03f000 - 0x3a054fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <3ee61a04a99b322e97e179bc03c46cf1> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x3a079000 - 0x3a0fefff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <cbefd01867b93d2a869a534825a1414c> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3a0ff000 - 0x3a14afff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <e3154b06ac5d360c948111abfb2bc339> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x3a14b000 - 0x3a171fff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <c43990ee3a5e389aacf288c3615a50dc> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x3a175000 - 0x3a222fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <28dcf6ee713b387ebb763d11d4b3cd37> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x3a223000 - 0x3a243fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <d327d9e0f43333568abda8d83558c8a9> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x3a244000 - 0x3a250fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <3ea49513bc023326be68e35324c11d0e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x3a251000 - 0x3a254fff  libcache.dylib armv7  <91862e82d5063531b4fb4da9a19e5365> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x3a255000 - 0x3a25bfff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <d9e66574881739e8b25c3ae087a9f409> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x3a25c000 - 0x3a25efff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <6ac449c92d743640a23d9d1ebe0b48a9> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x3a25f000 - 0x3a264fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <87bcae8743ab35c8a070ac95b7d57acb> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x3a265000 - 0x3a29afff  libcorecrypto.dylib armv7  <04b464137fc2304b84eeed1a5418f4a8> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x3a29b000 - 0x3a2b8fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9323bb560d4e3a3fb41efdc78bd0cf94> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x3a2b9000 - 0x3a2bafff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <c25502085c833181b2a12cf525cffde6> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x3a2bb000 - 0x3a2bcfff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <82229500ed4132ecbe012e0774e5fc4a> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x3a2bd000 - 0x3a2bdfff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <e19c865e73e2352bbc8022033e953f22> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x3a2be000 - 0x3a2c3fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <c8bedc36bc3d3b55b91b12ebb1240968> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x3a2c4000 - 0x3a2c7fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <965ab939e24935e7a3a65981574a7745> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x3a2c8000 - 0x3a2c9fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <295706037a5238b4aa145df7b9354a0e> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x3a2ca000 - 0x3a2cafff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <50a01a02f573317fbd21e1070b0afc7d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x3a2cb000 - 0x3a351fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <cacc68d271e53338b7780c26f651b767> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x3a352000 - 0x3a358fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <6c5ac17133a1366aaeea5dc38dceaf1f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x3a359000 - 0x3a371fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <5a4a4c9da868317db7f17cb616eb32d1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x3a372000 - 0x3a388fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <8e995919df713a8783f23e7f6649bf09> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x3a389000 - 0x3a3a5fff  libsystem_m.dylib armv7  <036ea0321da038e8b69a0c4413da00fe> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x3a3a6000 - 0x3a3b4fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <afc167a2e9be3dd6851da8deaf42bafd> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x3a3b5000 - 0x3a3bcfff  libsystem_notify.dylib armv7  <c1d71aa978383c51a9ba2b32782d6cc6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x3a3bd000 - 0x3a3befff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <45bb99d46408351a9c61b5326032adea> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x3a3bf000 - 0x3a3bffff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <df8f1d90cbb837cc92d5901fab94e6ca> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x3a3c0000 - 0x3a3d5fff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <7f983066ea4c3c119f3e2344a04fef6e> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
```

Any hints?

Thanks in advance,

- AGPX

Comment: Did you find out the reason for this crash? The only hint I found so far was to set the kCFStreamPropertyFTPAttemptPersistentConnection to false, which is not a solution for me.

Comment: Nope, it's a bug of the SDK.